# Sound doesn't come out of external speakers

Tags: 16.04, sound, speakers

I have installed `Ubuntu 16.04.1` on my new computer. I am playing music from the internal laptop speakers and sound does come out. Plugging in the external speakers still output sound from the internal laptop speakers!

I have plugged in my phone to the external speakers and it works great.
I have followed [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting) manual, but it didn't help (the basic troubleshooting step).

Here are some information, if you need anything else please tell me.

```
itai@Negev:~$ sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


itai@Negev:~$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 130
    Memory at dfc28000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at dfc00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```